# Gitlab CI/CD - How to know when a process has finished

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I'm trying to start a test after an Angular project is compiled.
The problem is that when the project is finally compiled, the process its still
alive (`ng serve`), so the test doesn't start. (I use cypress for testing!)
The best I've done is making both jobs, simultaneous in the same stage and one manual paused
waiting for the other to finish, but my end goal is to make it automatic somehow.

This is the code:

```
    image: node:12.20
    
    cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules/
        
    stages:
      - test
    
    job-prepare:
      stage: test
      script:
        - node -v
        - npm -v
        - npm i
        - npm install -g @angular/cli@9.0.6
        - ng version
        - npm run serve:windows
     
    job-test:
      stage: test
      script:
        - npm run e2e
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
```

Thanks

Comment: `serve` command used to start server, but not for testing. for testing use https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: I use cypress to test, so I need the project to be running, as a temporal solution I've used: `when: delayed start_in: (average compile time)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not using only one job with `before_script` and `script` by putting the compilation into `before_script` and the testing inside `script` ?

https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script

Comment: Because the process of compiling has to be on (never finishes), so the job doesn't finish either and never goes to the next job (testing)

Comment: Using `before_script`  and `after_script` would only be one job. Why not running your compilation in the background then, with `&`  ?